# Spring Boot CXF XMLOutputFactory cannot be created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I'm trying to launch my Spring Boot application from `java` command and I  got the following error when I open the WSDL:

Note that I can open the WSDL when I run the application from Eclipse.

Is there any Idea?

> Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path
>   [/bootapp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with
>   root cause java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
>           at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.getXMLOutputFactory(StaxUtils.java:295)
>           at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(StaxUtils.java:392)
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.writeXml(SchemaSerializer.java:56)
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.marshall(SchemaSerializer.java:49)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printExtensibilityElements(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printTypes(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printDefinition(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.writeWSDLDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:705)
>           at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.getDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:151)
>           at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.getDocument(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:129)
>           at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.handleMessage(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:77)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 2018-02-22 15:51:12 - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: Can you post the code that opens the WSDL? It looks like Spring is trying to extract a file from a corrupt ZIP archive.

Comment: Your question lacks version of Spring Boot, CXF and source code.

Answer (score 0):

the follwinf fix in pom exclusion solve the problem finaly:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- <exclusion> -->
                <!-- <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
                <!-- <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId> -->
                <!-- </exclusion> -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId> -->
                    <!-- <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId> -->
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.18</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
<!--                <exclusion> -->
<!--                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId> -->
<!--                    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId> -->
<!--                </exclusion> -->
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId> -->
                    <!-- <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId> -->
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a starter and excluding so many dependencies?

Comment: i excluded them for fixing maven confilcts issues, but the solution for the question is with the stax and woodstox-core dependencies wich make confilcts with the others getted from the jar spring-boot version 1..5.9-release